# Browsers are giving different jquery errors in the result of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm tying to validate and upload images using multiple accept input using jquery, ajax and php. I added validation function which is working properly, but form does not submitting, also chrome and firefox showing different errors in console.

### HTML

```
<form id="promotionImageForm_<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>"  autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Add More Images</label>
    <input type="file"  name="pm_image[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="pmMultiImgs_<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pm_id" value="<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="uploadImageByID" value="uploadImageByID" />
    <button type="button" onclick="return multiImageUpload(<?php echo $row['pm_id']; ?>);" id="pmMultibTn" />Add</button>
</form>
```

### JS Function

```
function uploadImageByID(formData){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'response.php',
        data:formData,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(response){
            $(".pmImgPopNoti").remove();
            if(response.success){
                $(".pmRes_"+promotionImageID).prepend('<div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-success pmImgPopNoti col-sm-12">'+response.success+'</div>');                   
            }
            if(response.error){
                $(".pmRes_"+promotionImageID).prepend('<div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger pmImgPopNoti col-sm-12">'+response.error+'</div>');
            }   
        }
    });
}   
function multiImageUpload(pmID){
    $('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID).validate();
    $('#pmMultiImgs_'+pmID).each(function() {
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png",
            messages: {
                accept: "Only jpeg, jpg or png images"
            }
        });
    });
    if ($('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID).valid()) {
        var formDetail = $('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID);
        var formData = new FormData(formDetail);
            uploadImageByID(formData);
            return false;
    }
}
```

**Chrome Showing This Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

**FireFox Showing This Error**

> TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.
>   var formData = new FormData(formDetail);

Can anyone guide me how can i fix this error. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You

Comment: It seems like it expect the Form element itself, and not the jquery element. 
Try this:
var formDetail = $('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID).get(0);

Comment: @MartinMouritzen I tried but now firefox giving this error `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.` and in chrome still this error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FormData` object constructor expects a `form` element, not a jQuery object containing a form. Try this:

```
if ($('#promotionImageForm_'+pmID).valid()) {
    var formDetail = $('#promotionImageForm_' + pmID);
    var formData = new FormData(formDetail[0]); // note [0] here
    uploadImageByID(formData);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried, still giving this error `TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.`

Comment: Also Chrome still giving same error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: I also just added `processData: false,` after `data:formData`, now its working. Thanks for sharing knowledge.